# Call a Julia function from a larger Fortran program

Tags: fortran, julia

I am trying to solve the following problem, but I am not sure that there is an answer...

I have a very large program, written in Fortran. It is quite old, but I don't want to write it in Julia (it would take too much time).
On the other hand, I have a Julia function that uses several complex packages that would perfectly improve my Fortran program. Once again, translate the Julia function into Fortran would take a lot of time.
For the moment, my function has the following form `output(x::Vector{Float64})::Vector{Float64}` and I have little control over the code inside it. So, imagine that it is a "blackbox".

Then, I was wondering if there was a way to make it work. One simple idea would be to call a Julia script that would store the output in a file and then Fortran would read the file to fetch the output. However, the function needs to be called multiple times, so that might slow down a lot the execution. I tried to produce a shared library using `compile_shlib` from `StaticCompiler.jl`, but this produces undefined symbols in the `.so` file that gfortran hates at compilation.

```
> nm output.so
0000000000004018 b completed.0
                 w __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000001060 t deregister_tm_clones
00000000000010d0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000003df0 d __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000004010 d __dso_handle
0000000000003df8 d _DYNAMIC
00000000000011c0 t _fini
0000000000001110 t frame_dummy
0000000000003de8 d __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
00000000000020b4 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000003fe8 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w __gmon_start__
000000000000200c r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
                 U ijl_apply_generic
                 U ijl_type_error
0000000000001000 t _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000001120 T julia_myfunc_
0000000000001090 t register_tm_clones
0000000000004018 d __TMC_END__
```

Is there a "smart" way to make it work?

Comment: Follow the documentation for embedding in C and use the Fortran-C interoperability. https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/embedding/ Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65322339/how-to-use-julia-special-functions-inside-c